# Extract session key from encrypted message (envelope)

Tags: encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, session-keys

I have a hard time to extract session key (symmetric key) from encrypted message envelope (Bouncy Castle encrypted).

I have read [that](http://flylib.com/books/en/1.274.1/cms_and_s_mime.html) documentation where states only that

> with a field of the type EncryptedKey representing the bytes making up
>   the wrapped symmetric key used to encrypt the data enveloped in the
>   message and the KeyEncryptionAlgorithmIdentifier representing the
>   algorithm that was used to do the wrapping.

but it doesn't say how to decrypt message not using Bouncy Castle but when utilize own created parser and for that I need to have a session key first.

Comment: It's CMS-formatted, so you're going to need a CMS library to parse it.

Comment: @JamesKPolk You mean Bouncy Castle CMS library like `CMSEnvelopedDataParser` or there are some other "lightweight"?

Comment: @JamesKPolk On another hand is there any way to get symmetric key an store when a message is encrypted in the Bouncy Castle?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Also does a symmetric key  (wrapped) is stored in the envelope as (unprotected) attribute?